# DB2 equivalent of Oracle DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR etc

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5

I have to migrate an Oracle stored procedure to DB2 LUW 10.5. It uses `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR()` function on a `BLOB` parameter that receives an array of bytes from the client code.

What is its equivalent in DB2? `SUBSTRB` seems fitting, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [`DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0055128.html), introduced in Db2 for LUW 9.7 as part of the Oracle compatibility feature?

If you are migrating from Oracle consider reading about [that feature](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/t0054729.html) and [how to use it](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247736.html), it might save you some effort.

Plain old [`SUBSTR`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000854.html?pos=2) will work as well.